# Upload multiple files URLs in db with Yii2

Tags: image, postgresql, url, upload, yii2

I'm having a problem with uploading multiple files names in postgresql with Yii2, I have a table named "i006t_factura" with an iD, a foreign key named "id_obra" and a "ruta" which is where I want to save the image file, but if I have multiple files, then I have to save multiple names for that "id_obra", so this is my code for my **model:**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
* This is the model class for table "i006t_factura".
*
* @property integer $id
* @property integer $id_obra
* @property string $ruta
*
* @property C004tObraSocial $idObra
*/
class Factura extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $ruta;
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'i006t_factura';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id'], 'required'],
        [['id_obra'], 'required'],
        [['id_obra'], 'integer'],
        [['ruta'], 'safe'],
        [['ruta'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png',
            'maxFiles' => 8,],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id_obra' => 'Id Obra',
        'ruta' => 'Ruta',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getIdObra()
{
    return $this->hasOne(C004tObraSocial::className(), ['id' => 'id_obra']);
}

public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    if(isset($this->ruta)){
        $this->ruta=UploadedFiles::getInstance($this,'ruta');
        if(is_object($this->ruta)){
            $path=Yii::$app->basePath . '/archivos/';  //set directory path to save image
            $this->ruta->saveAs($path.$this->id_obra."_".$this->ruta);   //saving img in folder
            $this->ruta = $this->id_obra."_".$this->ruta;    //appending id to image name            
            \Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
            ->update('organization', ['ruta' => $this->ruta], 'id = "'.$this->id_obra.'"')
            ->execute(); //manually update image name to db
        }
    }
}
```

}

My **controller**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Factura;
use app\models\FacturaSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
* FacturaController implements the CRUD actions for Factura model.
*/
class FacturaController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
               'verbs' => [
                   'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                   'actions' => [
                   'delete' => ['post'],
                    ],
               ],
       ];
   }

/**
 * Lists all Factura models.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new FacturaSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Displays a single Factura model.
 * @param integer $id
 * @param integer $id_obra
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionView($id_obra)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id_obra),
    ]);
}

/**
 * Creates a new Factura model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Factura();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) &&($model->save()) ) {
        $model->ruta = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'ruta');
        if($model->ruta){
            $imagepath = 'archivos/'; // Create folder under web/uploads/logo
            $model->ruta = $imagepath .rand(10,100).'-'.$model->ruta->name;
        }
        if($model->ruta){
            $model->ruta->saveAs($model->ruta);
        }
        return $this->redirect(['view','id'=>$model->id, 'id_obra' => $model->id_obra]);

    }else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);

    }
}

/**
 * Updates an existing Factura model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @param integer $id_obra
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionUpdate($id_obra)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id_obra);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        $model->ruta = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'ruta');

        if($model->file){
            $imagepath = 'archivos/';
            $model->ruta = $imagepath .rand(10,100).'-'.$model->ruta->name;
        }

        if($model->ruta){
            $model->file->saveAs($model->logo);
            return $this->redirect(['view','id'=>$model->id, 'id_obra' => $model->id_obra]);
        }
    }  else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

public function actionDeleteimg($id_obra)
{

    $ruta = Factura::find()-where(['id'=>$id_obra])->one()->ruta;
    if($ruta){
        if (!unlink($ruta)) {
        return false;
    }
}

    $factura = Factura::findOne($id_obra);
    $factura->ruta = NULL;
    $factura->update();

    return $this->redirect(['update', 'id_obra' => $id_obra]);
}

/**
 * Deletes an existing Factura model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
 * @param integer $id
 * @param integer $id_obra
 * @return mixed
 */
public function actionDelete($id,$id_obra)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();
    $this->findModel($id_obra)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}

/**
 * Finds the Factura model based on its primary key value.
 * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
 * @param integer $id
 * @param integer $id_obra
 * @return Factura the loaded model
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
 */
 protected function findModel($id_obra)
 {
     if (($model = Factura::findOne(['id_obra' => $id_obra])) !== null) {
         return $model;
     } else {
         throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
       }
 }
}
```

And my **_form.php**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Factura */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="factura-form">

     <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

     <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->textInput() ?>

     <?= $form->field($model, 'id_obra')->textInput() ?>

     <?= $form->field($model, "ruta[]")->fileInput( ['multiple'=>true])?>
     <?php
     if ($model->ruta) {
          echo '<img src="'.\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/'.$model->ruta.'"   width="90px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
          echo Html::a('Delete Logo', ['deleteimg', 'id'=>$model->id, 'field'=> 'ruta'], ['class'=>'btn btn-danger']).'<p>';
     }
     ?>


    <div class="form-group">
         <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

    </div>
```

The error is when it want to upload an image, where "ruta" is null because it's not detecting the URL, I don't know if I need an iterative cycle in some part of my code!

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I resolved part of the problem, which is save the image url, but for ONE image! When I try to use the getInstances for multiple images, still have an error!

This is the actionCreate() from my controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Factura();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        // Here is where I obtain the image 
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
        if($model->file){
            $imagepath = 'archivos/'; 
            $model->ruta = $imagepath .rand(10,100).'-'.$model->file->name;
        }

        if($model->save()){
            if($model->file){
                $model->file->saveAs($model->ruta);
            }   
             return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id, 'id_obra' => $model->id_obra]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And this is my updated _form.php:

```
 <div class="factura-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->textInput() ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'id_obra')->textInput() ?>
//Where I submit my image
<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

So, still have the multiple images problem... don't know it has to do with the db table...